# how to solve NaN error

Tags: java, nan

this is the code for calculating average and I'm getting NaN error when i run my project

```
public  static double calculateAverage(){
    double attendence = 0;
    int no_of_matches = 0;
    double average =0;
        for (Team t: ApplicationModel.getTeamList()){
        for(Match m : ApplicationModel.getMatchList()){
                if(m.getTeamname().equals(t.getName())){
                    attendence =+ (m.getAttendence());
                    no_of_matches ++;   
                }
            }
            average = attendence / no_of_matches ;
    } 
        return average;
}
```

this is the code of calling the calculating average method

```
String[] columnNames = {"Name","Coaches","League","Division","Fulltime","Number of Coaches","Average Attendence"};

 if (ApplicationModel.getTeamList()!=null){
     int arrayIndex=0;
     for (Team c :ApplicationModel.getTeamList()){
           String[] currentRow = new String[7];
           currentRow[0] = c.getNameAsString();
           currentRow[1] = c.getCoachesAsString();
           currentRow[2] = c.getLeague();
           currentRow[3] = c.getDivision();
           currentRow[4] = c.getFulltime();
           currentRow[5] = Integer.toString(c.getCoaches().length);
           currentRow[6] = Double.toString(c.calculateAverage());
           rowInfo[arrayIndex]=currentRow;
           arrayIndex++;
           teamDisplay.append(c.toString());
         }
        }
```

Comment: Maybe you are dividing by 0 here `average = attendence / no_of_matches ;`?

Comment: If you're getting NaN, it means that you divide floating zero by zero.

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem might be this line of code:

```
attendence =+ (m.getAttendence());
```

Instead of adding the value to the total variable, you assign the total variable to the value. Another problem is the fact that you do not handle the case where `no_of_matches` (which is a terrible variable name in terms of naming conventions) is `0`, i.e. there are no matches. Last of all, `average = attendence / no_of_matches` always re-assigns the `average`, thus discarding any results from the previous team.

Code Suggestion:

```
double attendence = 0;
int matches = 0;
for (Team t: ApplicationModel.getTeamList())
{
    for(Match m : ApplicationModel.getMatchList())
    {
        if(m.getTeamname().equals(t.getName()))
        {
            attendence += (m.getAttendence());
            matches++;
        }
    }
} 
return matches > 0 ? attendence / matches : 0D;
```

Comment: thank you ver much for the help. its work but calculating average for only one thats why printing 0.0

Answer (score 0):

I think you can fix the NAN error checking if `no_of_matches > 0` before use it in the division operation.

```
public static double calculateAverage(){
    double attendence = 0;
    int no_of_matches = 0;
    double average = 0;

    for (Team t: ApplicationModel.getTeamList()) {
        for (Match m: ApplicationModel.getMatchList()) {
            if (m.getTeamname().equals(t.getName())) {
                attendence =+ (m.getAttendence());
                no_of_matches ++;   
            }
        }

        if (no_of_matches > 0)
            average = attendence / no_of_matches ;
    }

    return average;
}
```

An aditional note, when you add this check and `no_of_matches` is `0` your average will be 0, that means you have no matches.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Its coming as 0.0, now i know the problem. I want to get average for all three but it only calculating for one team probably thats why